# PHP session validation with cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies

I currently have 2 pages, one a log in page, and when the log in details are correct, it redirects the user to the gold page. However  you can just access the gold page through the URL and i only want it to open if the user logs in.

```html
<?php



?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Log-in</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Please enter your username and password</p>


  <form method="post">
   <input type="integer" name="userID"/>
   <input type="text" name="password"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
  </form>



   <?php




    $i = $_POST["userID"];
    $j = $_POST["password"];
    $gold_cookie = "gold";



     if (isset($i) && $i == "2" && isset($j) && $j=="hi") {


session_start();

$_SESSION['login_user']= $i;


      setcookie($gold_cookie , time()+30) ;


      header("Location:gold.php");


     }

     if (isset($i) && $i != "2" && isset($j) && $j !="hi") {


           echo "Get lost bro!";
     }

     $_SESSION ["first_name"] = "Kevin";
     $name = $_SESSION ["first_name"];




   ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

```html
html>
 <head>
  <title>Log-in</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>You have made it!</p>


  <p> TAKE SOME GOLD </p>

<img src="http://ei.marketwatch.com//Multimedia/2013/04/19/Photos/MG/MW-BB708_GoldUs_20130419105117_MG.jpg?uuid=9fd4d8c0-a900-11e2-a57c-002128040cf6">

 </body>
</html>
```

Could somebody direct me into the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in gold.php at the beginning:

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
    die('Not authorized');
}
```

But I would advise to use a php framework. A simple framework with routing like SlimPHP, will make such things much easier and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add an if statement in your gold page :

if(User is logged in)
{
   //Your gold page code
}
else /**redirect user to the login page*/
{
   header("Location: login_page.php");
}
```